# reset selectedvalue when textbox change

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a textbox and a dropdownlist

the textbox has

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtInizioPeriodo" runat="server" 
                        ontextchanged="InizioPeriodo_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" Width="100"></asp:TextBox>
```

i want if it changes the dropdownlist return to default value selected
i try to pur in page load this:

```
SelectDestinazione[i].SelectedValue = "";
```

but it now works.
how can i do?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you have mentioned like

Array of Dropdownlist ie.,

```
SelectDestinazione[i].SelectedValue = "";
```

in the above code "i" selects dropdownlist object from the array of dropdownlists.

Kindly check that one. If its is the single dropdownlist box then use the below solution.

Copy & paste the below code in the server side during the text content change event.

```
  protected void InizioPeriodo_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      SelectDestinazione.SelectedIndex = -1;
  }
```

Comment: thanks it worked with

protected void InizioPeriodo_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      SelectDestinazione.SelectedValue = "";
  }

Answer (score 0):

I assume SelectDestinazione is your dropdownlist

SelectDestinazione.clearSelection();